# Apply fft on video as 4D array

Tags: fft, image-processing, frequency-response, video

I working on a project called " eulerian video magnification " and i want to apply FFT on video and get the frequency response from the video . I have gotten 4D array ( frames,width,high,RGBchannel). Which steps should i do ? I am doing the implementation on Labview but it will he helpfully to know just the algorithm then try to apply on any program. For any suggestions i will be thankful .

Comment: Hi. Welcome here. So, this is all based on a rather well written paper, and that paper has a flow chart that very well gives an overview of what you then have to implement according to section 3. If that is too condensed, there's also the dissertation on the topic. Can you tell us what you've tried, where you're stuck trying to understand or implement this paper? Otherwise, your question is too broad and also kind of asking us to do your assignment without showing any own attempt, both officially reasons to close it on this site.

Comment: Good morning , right is all written in the paper from RobsteinPhdThesis . But it didn't explain in detail about the temporal filtering ( here where i am stuck) otherwise i need to understand how to get  from video as 4D array a 1D signal over time .

Comment: so, this question is too broad. Please *do* explain where you're stuck. We can't help you otherwise.